# Subir Imágenes en Laravel con Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

estoy tratando de subir una imagen en un proyecto de Laravel 5.4, pero no consigo hacerlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar por favor. He visto tutoriales, y lo estoy haciendo así pero no consigo nada.

Tengo mi Vista:

```
<form name="form_add" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Imagen (*)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagen">
</div>
```

El código de donde envío el ajax:

```
 var form = document.forms.namedItem("form_add");
 var formdata = new FormData(form);

 $.ajax({
      async: true,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      url: 'landing-productos',
      data: formdata,
      processData: false,
 });
```

Y el controlador:

```
$producto = new LandingProducto();
  $file = $request->file('imagen');
  $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $path = public_path().'/img/articulos/';
  $file->move($path, $nombre);
  $producto->imagen = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: te hace falta poner en el ajax el header con el x-crsf token para que te funcione el ajax.

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo mas facil es agregarle un action a tu form y generar una nueva ruta:
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'insertar-imagen','method' => 'post','role' => 'form','files'=>'true')) }}
//TODO EL FORMULARIO
{{Form::close()}}

Ruta:
Route::any('insertar-imagen', 'Controlador@insertImagen');

Controlador, recibes por parametro $request:

```
$file = $request->file('imagen');
$nombre =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::put($nombre, file_get_contents($file));
```

En app/config/filesystems.php estan los storage de almacenamiento, en este ejemplo usa el local el cual deberia tener la siguiente configuracion:

'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('/img/articulos/'),
        ],

Saludos